# strange: function not defined

Tags: javascript, html, xml, dom

I have write the following in my  element:

```
<form name="myform" method="POST" id="location">
<input type="text" name="URL" maxlength="255" size="100" value="" />
<br />
<input type="button" onclick="loadXML(this.form)" name="submit" value="Submit Query" />
</form>
```

Then I have defined my function loadXML() in the  part in the ; but every I try to run this html, the firefox shows this:

ReferenceError:loadXML is not defined
    loadXML(this.form)

I have checked my code for so many times I am sure there is no spell mistakes, how does this happen? How can I correct it? Thank you!

Comment: where is your loadXML function defined ?

Comment: In the <head>, I write all the javascript in <script></script>.

Comment: Can you post the head section? are you sure it's defined as a global function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`loadXML` is only available in IE.  Otherwise, you want to use the [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOMParser) object.  In fact, I would rely on *that* existing first:

```
if (typeof DOMParser !== 'undefined') {
    var dom = new DOMParser();
    dom.parseFromString(this.form, "application/xml");
}
else {
    loadXML(this.form);
}
```

Comment: This html will only be loaded through firefox, so I don't think this problem is related to browser. The most strange thing is I definitely defined loadXML but it shows I didn't.